# Transferring multiple files though Informatica FTP connection

Tags: ftp, connection, informatica

I have a requirement to generate the target file in Informatica with date/time appended to it. How will the Informatica FTP connection identify such dynamic file name with date appended to its name?
Also I would like to know if it is possible to FTP multiple files at a time via Informatica FTP connection. Please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty simple, you just have to use the part of the file name that is constant and then place a *

for eg:

Myfile_20190607.txt

Myfile_20190507.txt

If i specify Myfile_2019* , this is good enough to pickup the files soecified above. You may have to play with the * and criteria to fit the files that you need.

Note: if you are sending files to third party, try to use SFTP instead of plain old ftp and most organization blocked ftp to outside ip's.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know until Informatica 9.x, it is neither possible to generate dynamic filename nor create multiple files using FTP connection. Only option was to create the files on Informatica server and then run a script to FTP them over to the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

1. edit your workflow, choose variables tab, create a workflow
   variable with datatype NSTRING; assume the variable name is
   $wf_timestamp;
2. create an assignment task  and assign TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD')
   to the variable in the assignment task;
3. edit session: Choose Mapping tab, choose your target; then
   Connections; then edit FTP Value; then in the Remote Filename
   attribute, enter your filename with the timestemp, eg,
   myfile_$$$wf_timestamp.csv;

put your assignment before you session in your workflow. 
that's it.